# Should I instantiate a field when I use lombok

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, lombok

I use lombok to omit the getter and setter of a java bean.
Here is a example from the book "Spring in Action 5 edition"

A java bean:

```
@Data
public class Taco {

  @Size(min=1, message="You must choose at least 1 ingredient")
  private List<String> ingredients;

}
```

Controller:

```
  @PostMapping
  public String processDesign(@Valid @ModelAttribute("design") Taco design, Errors errors, Model model) {
    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
      return "design";
    }
    System.out.println(design.getIngredients());    
    return "redirect:/orders/current";
  }
```

The rendered view:

```
<form method="POST">
        <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" value="FLTO">
        <span>Flour Tortilla</span><br>

        <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" value="GRBF">
        <span>Ground Beef</span><br>

</form>
```

When I submit the form and no checkbox is checked,the validation does not work,in the controller, `errors.hasErrors()` is false,and `design.getIngredients()` is `null`

Then I change the code in the java bean:

```
  private List<String> ingredients=new ArrayList<>();
```

validation works,user will get the message:"You must choose at least 1 ingredient"

But my question is : should I instantiate a field even I already used lombok,especially for a reference field?Is there a way use an annotation to do it?

Comment: This is *initializing* a field, and it's perfectly normal to do this in conjunction with Lombok annotations if you want to assign a default value (like an empty `ArrayList`).

Comment: Does it work if you replace `@Size` by `@NotEmpty`?

Comment: @JanRieke works in this case,only one annotation do exactly want I expect.But If I want users to select at least two items,I must use both `@NotEmpty` and `@Size(min=2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the nullary constructor and initialize the `List` inside it. Lomboks constructor will be overridden.

```
@Data
public class Taco {

  @Size(min=1, message="You must choose at least 1 ingredient")
  private List<String> ingredients;

  public Taco() {
     ingredients = new ArrayList<>()
  }

}
```

Comment: But I still must do it manually,why didn't lombok help me do it automatically?

Comment: Lombok only adds constructors & getters/setters. Those are pretty straight-forward. Initializing members is beyond its scope. Think about how it would work. What if you needed a `LinkedList` instead of an `ArrayList`? It would be too complicated to do that with an annotation when you can do it much more simply by overriding the constructor.

Comment: But why not use a field initializer as suggested in the question? There should be no drawback, and it'd be less code.

Comment: Static initializers only run during class-loading. Using that for mutable types can be error-prone.

Comment: Field initializers are not static initializers.